# Auto Enable/Disable based on the Stock Status

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm trying to disable the product if it's out of stock and enabled if it's in stock

Here's the observer I created:

```
public function product_prepare_save($observer) {
        $product = $observer->getProduct();
        $stockData = $product->getStockData();

        if ( $product && $stockData['qty'] ) {

            $stockData->setData('is_in_stock', 1); // Set the Product to InStock
            Mage::getModel('catalog/product_status')->updateProductStatus($product->getProductId(), $storeId, Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED);      

        } else {
            Mage::getModel('catalog/product_status')->updateProductStatus($product->getProductId(), $storeId, Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED);
        }
    }
 }
```

What am I missing over here?

Comment: Which Event you are obeserving ?

Comment: I'm using this catalog_product_prepare_save

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This been tested and it works as it should be.

```
public function stockEnhancements(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        $storeId = 0;
        $product   = $observer->getProduct();
        $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item');
        $stockItem->assignProduct($product);

        //make sure stock qty is greater than zero.
        if (isset($stockItem['qty']) && $stockItem['qty'] >= 1) {

            $stockItem->setData('is_in_stock', 1);
            $stockItem->save();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
public function product_prepare_save($observer) {

    $product = $observer->getProduct();
    if($product && $product->getId()) {
        $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product);
        $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
        if ($stockItem->getIsInStock()) { 
           Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')
            ->updateAttributes(array($product->getId()), array('status' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED), $storeId);
        }else{
            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')
            ->updateAttributes(array($product->getId()), array('status' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED), $storeId);

        }    
    }
}
```

**OR**

```
public function product_prepare_save($observer) {

    $product = $observer->getProduct();
    if($product && $product->getId()) {
        $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
        if ($product->getStockItem()->getIsInStock()) {
           Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')
            ->updateAttributes(array($product->getId()), array('status' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED), $storeId);
        }else{
            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')
            ->updateAttributes(array($product->getId()), array('status' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED), $storeId);

        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution won't work, as I want to check whether the qty is => 1 or  < 1 then it should enable and put the product back in stock if it's => 1 if not then it should disable the product as simple as that, I hope that make sense.